# Is it wise to create object of class in the same php class file?

Tags: php, class, oop

I am a newbie in php oop. My question is is it wise to create object/instance of class in the same class file? like this:
myclass.php

```
<?php
class myClass{
    public $a
    function myFunction()
        echo $this->a;
    }
}
$obj= new myClass;
$obj->$a='This is my class file';
?>
```

Probably this is wellknown to all expert of php but this is very new and basic concept for me.

Comment: Even if you get rid of syntax errors, `$this` isn't valid outside. It should be referenced as `$obj->a`.

Comment: your code wont work. do you have a opening brace for myFunction?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I edited it. But my concern is not that. Please look that I initialized class in the same file (myclass.php). Usually class files are included in another php file and in the another php file that class is initialized. If I initialize the class in the same class file, will it be right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule preventing instantiation of the class in the same file it was defined. It all comes down to what exactly you want to do with it.

For example, you could have a static method that instantiates the class and returns the instance. This is useful for implementing the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It is however considered bad practice to have global variables like the variable `$obj` you're defining in your example.

If all you want to do is initialize the instance as it's being created, then you should do so in [the constructor](http://php.net/oop5.decon).

For example, the `MyClass` class could reside in a `MyClass.php` file:

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    private $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = 'This is my class file';
    }

    public function myFunction() {
        return $this->a;
    }
}
```

Then, in the file you actually want to use a `MyClass` instance, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'MyClass.php';

$myInstance = new MyClass();
echo $myInstance->myFunction();
```

Comment: Dear rid, If I will not declare it global (public), then how can I set value of $a from outside class, in a argument of public function by making the property $a private?

Comment: @stockBoi, you can create [accessor methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Accessor_and_mutator_methods) such as `getA()` and `setA($a)`. Ideally, the class should encapsulate all its data and only provide a way of working with its methods, not of directly manipulating its internal data. This way, descendants could override the accessors for example and provide extra functionality. Or, you could have a setter that does not directly affect a property, for example. Either way, the class internal data should be kept internal and the user should only call methods.

Comment: @stockBoi, also, when talking about global variables, I was referring to `$obj`, not to the public property `$a`.

Comment: Dear rid, as you said that you were talking about $obj, then I am more confused as I am newbie to php oop. Would you please give me the code for above situation?

Comment: @stockBoi, example added. For more about OOP in PHP, you should take a look at the manual entries under [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/oop), which go into more detail about how classes are created and used in PHP.